# How can I integrate scrapy with my flask app?

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping, scrapy

I have an application that has requirement of scrapping data from several websites, I have been able to scrap the data using the scrapy library of python, but the issue is I want to have the feature where I can call my spider using rest APIs.

How can I achieve that, as I don't want that extra step of first scraping the data and then saving it at the backend and then fetching it using the APIs?

Any help would be highly appreciated. I have already tried Arachne, but I am unable to return JSON response from the scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at `scrapyd`: https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

It allows you to deploy your spiders and control them using a JSON API.